# Prestashop New string to translate doesn't appear in my back-office

Tags: prestashop

I'm having a very stupid issue with a new string I need to translate. I added it into my theme file :

File: /themes//order-carrier.tpl

```
{*Displaying a link to CMS page*} 
{if $carrier.id_carrier == 36} 
    <a href="{$link->getCMSLink(21)}" target="_blank">{l s="My new string"}</a>
{/if}
```

But when I go to my back-office to translate the string, I can't find this new string (Tools > Translations) ...

I'm using Prestashop 1.4.9 and I disabled Smarty's cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was because I used double quotes instead of a single quote in this line : {l s="My new string"}

Cf: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/376146-cant-translate-strings-from-included-tpl-in-a-custom-module/

Comment: i got this {l s='Benefits' mod='openpayprestashop'} and didn't work anyway

Comment: Have you defined the translation in the back-end ? Is the module "openpayprestashop" active ?

Comment: Was something dumb... I didn't scroll down the page